# Why my postman doesn't show my schema yearfounded and revenue?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When I run my http requests in postman, my schema number doesn't show. It shows null.

``const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const OrganisationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  yearFounded: Number,
  revenue: Number
}, {
  timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Organisations', OrganisationSchema);

```
{"name": "MadHouse", "yearFounded": "1988", "revenue": "100"}


{
    "_id": "5d0d04523668a64609bd20a2",
    "name": "Untitled Organisation",
    "createdAt": "2019-06-21T16:22:42.974Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-06-21T16:24:29.956Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "revenue": null,
    "yearFounded": null
}
```

Comment: Would be better if you share more about your context. For example: How is this call being made? What the content of the OrganisationSchema?
Fell fell to share your code, so we can help you.

Comment: I have added the content above. I

Comment: For what I'm seeing, you are setting revenue as a Number, but your json is showing a string. Try fixing this.

Comment: Is it I have to give the number without quotes?

Comment: Yes! just "revenue": 100

Comment: It didn't work like that too.

Comment: {"name": "MadHouse", "yearFounded": 1988, "revenue": 100}

Comment: {
    "_id": "5d0d0b111f54464699d8afb0",
    "name": "Untitled Organisation",
    "createdAt": "2019-06-21T16:51:29.648Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-06-21T16:52:51.182Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "revenue": null,
    "yearFounded": null
}

Comment: Can you share all your code?

Comment: module.exports = (app) => {
  const organisations = require('../controllers/organisation.controller.js');
  app.post('/organisations', organisations.create);
  app.get('/organisations', organisations.findAll);

  app.get('/organisations/:organisationId', organisations.findOne);
  app.put('/organisations/:organisationId', organisations.update);
  app.delete('/organisations/:organisationId', organisations.delete);
}

Answer (score 0):

This should be the problem with your insertion or retrieval of data. Just to confirm make revenue and year as required then try inserting.

Comment: No even when I changed it doesn't retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

I just got home and downloaded you project from github, and was able to run it on my machine. And like I said, when the revenue field is sent as a Number, it's works fine.

[image: Post Request]

[image: Get Request]

Here is the JSON on the database:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5d0d55eb2b177faf109d53e3"), 
"name" : "Teste", 
"yearFounded" : NumberInt(2019), 
"revenue" : 145.8, 
"createdAt" : ISODate("2019-06-21T22:10:51.634+0000"), 
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-06-21T22:10:51.634+0000"), 
"__v" : NumberInt(0) }
```

Try to simulate the same data I sent, and check if you're still getting the same bad behavior.

Comment: I was using wrong port and I wasn't viewing as JSON. That's the reason for getting it as null. This is my first CRUD api, learning it from mistakes. Thank you.